# Free source for yellow pages data?

Tags: web-scraping

Is there a free source with basic yellow pages data(name,address, phone#)?  I don't mind if its out of date.  I couldn't find anything with google.  To clarify I'm looking for a data dump, I know I can just go to yellow pages.com or whatever for regular queries.  As a last resort I'll probably scrape it.

Comment: Be aware that scraping the data periodically could be against their terms of service, or possibly illegal, and could get you banned from their site.

Comment: Do you need some random data for testing or stuff like that? Maybe you could try [Mockaroo](https://www.mockaroo.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sort of data tends to be very expensive, so you're unlikely to find anyone offering a free directory. If they are it will probably be horribly out of date or have many duplicates.

In my previous job the company was looking at business directories - the main stumbling block was the cost of good, clean data.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I'd recommend something like Yellabot.com and get the GOLD version if you can and automate scraping the data. I don't know of anywhere that is going to give that data out for free but if you're willing to pay for it, I'm sure there are companies that would sell the whole shebang for 10's of 1000's of dollars. If you do find it though, let me know, lol.